# how to break apart a large obj model and large single texture into smaller models with seaparate textures

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling

I have a large 3d model in .obj format with a large 20000*20000 texture. (it was generated by photogrammetry) I need to keep all the texture detail but want to use it with the Unity game engine. Unity only supports textures up to 8192*8192 so i think i need to break the model into smaller pieces and generate smaller textures(below 8192) from the original file.

How can i do this so i get separate textures for each piece? i.e. each model doesn't use the same large texture? I have access to 3DS Max

Answer (score 0):

This is not the website to get those kind of answers. Autodesk has their own websites for asking these types of questions.